# Spring boot application takes time to load the index page on daily razor tomcat hosting plan

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, thymeleaf

after developing my spring boot application, everything works fine on my local machine. It does not take time to load the index page and subsequent files. The loading speed is fantastic.

The problem is when i hosted the same application on daily razor java hosting plan, it takes lots of time to load the index page. I checked the stdout.log file everything seems to be fine.

Why is it taking too long to load the index page?

Comment: What plan do you have. The VM size seams to be very small

Comment: i guess so. I have contacted the hosting company about it. I was thinking there is another way one can manipulate that using java code.